# Are Strings also static: String creation within Methods

Tags: java, string, static

I know that at compile time when a `String` is created, that String will be THE string used by any objects of that particular signature.

`String s = "foo";`  <--Any other identical strings will simply be references to this object.

Does this hold for strings created during methods at runtime?  I have some code where an object holds a piece of string data.  The original code is something like

```
for(datum :data){
    String a = datum.getD();  //getD is not doing anything but returning a field

    StringBuffer toAppend = new StringBuffer(a).append(stuff).toString();

    someData = someObject.getMethod(a);
    //do stuff

}
```

Since the `String` was already created in `data`, it seems better to just call `datum.getD()` instead of creating a string on every iteration of the loop.

Unless there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String` instances are shared when they are the result of a compile-time constant expression.  As a result, in the example below `a` and `c` will point to the same instance, but `b` will be a different instance, even though they all represent the same value:

```
String a = "hello";
String b = hell() + o();
String c = "hell" + "o";

public String hell() {
   return "hell";
}

public String o() {
   return "o";
}
```

You *can* explicitly intern the String however:

```
String b = (hell() + o()).intern();
```

In which case they'll all point to the same object.

Comment: I was not aware of .intern()  
This answers the grander question I was driving at.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
 String a = datum.getD();
```

means, assign the result of evaluating `datum.getD()` to the reference `a` . It doesn't create a new String.

Comment: Yeah I think he knows that.  Read the second last sentence.

Comment: @Mark - maybe he does, maybe he doesn't.  It is hard to tell *what* his code is supposed to mean ... and hence what he is really asking about.

Comment: @Stephen: *"it seems better to just call datum.getD() instead of creating a string"*...seems he knows quite clearly that `datum.getD()` doesn't create a string.  He said so himself.

Comment: @Stephen: I will give you that it's confusing as to what the OP's alternative would be in this case.

Comment: Since this is in a for loop, ever iteration a new reference is created to the string in datum.getD()
My thinking is that I already have what I want in my data collection.  Why create a new reference every iteration instead of just calling for my data?

Answer (score -2):

You are correct that strings are immutable so all references to the same string value use the same object.
As far as being static, I do not think Strings are static in the way you describe. The `Class` class is like that, but I think it is the only object that does that.

I think it would be better to just call the `datum.getD()` since there is nothing that pulling it out into its own sting object gains for you.

If you do use the `datum.getD()` several times in the loop, then it might make sense to pull the value into a String object, because the cost of creating a string object once might be less than the cost of calling the `getD()` function multiple times.

Comment: You can definitely have two String instances that represent the same string. So your first sentence is wrong. Also: `datum.getD()` most likely *doesn't* create a new `String` object each time it's called (especially if it's a normal getter as its name implies).